# Haskell RandomGen for new matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix

I have to implement this function in haskell:

```
insertRandomNumber :: RandomGen g => [[Int]] -> g -> ([[Int]], g)
```

The function inserts a random number at a random position in my matrix. I can insert only at a position where there is a 0. The matrix size is 4 x 4 . I have this :

```
insertRandomNumber :: RandomGen g => [[Int]] -> g -> ([[Int]], g)
insertRandomNumber mat g =
    let (pos,_) = randomR (1,16) g
        ok = free (pos `div` 4) (pos `mod` 4) mat
    in if ok == True 
       then newmatrix pos mat 
       else insertRandomNumber mat g
```

The problem is that if the first position is not free, my program will block on else. 
I hope you can give me a example of how to use randomgen to insert a random number to a FREE random position.

Comment: Hint: [why do you need to explicitly thread the random generator in the first place?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Style nitpicking: `ok == True` is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You need to retain your new random number generator and pass that instead of the old generator.  Failure to do so means you will always generate the same `pos` on every iteration and loop forever.

In code:

```
let (pos,_) = randomR (1,16) g
```

Here you are explicitly ignoring the new RNG state.  Instead:

```
let (pos,newGen) = randomR (1,16) g
```

Then later you passed the old generator, which would generate the exact same `pos`:

```
in if ok == True then newmatrix pos mat else insertRandomNumber mat g
```

Instead, you should pass the new generator state:

```
in if ok == True then newmatrix pos mat else insertRandomNumber mat newGen
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split this problem into three parts: enumerate all indices which contain a 0, pick a random index out of these, and insert a random number at the chosen index. So something like this:

```
insertRandomNumber :: RandomGen g => [[Int]] -> g -> ([[Int]], g)
insertRandomNumber mat g0 = case validPositions mat of 
                             [] -> (mat, g0)
                             xs -> let (i,g1)  = randomR (0, length xs - 1) g0
                                       (v, g2) = randomR (1,100 :: Int) g1 
                                    in (replaceAt mat (xs !! i) v, g2)
```

I will leave you to write the functions `validPositions` and `replaceAt`.